# JPanel losing focus and listeners aren't firing

Tags: java, swing, events, jpanel, border-layout

So in my window, I set the `JFrame` to `undecorated(true)` and have my own custom header at the top (with closing and minimizing buttons). The only problem I'm having is making the window move when you drag this 'custom header'. The entire header is in a `JPanel` which is then added to the `JFrame` on the North side (`BorderLayout.NORTH`). I have a `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener` added to this `JPanel`, but it does not recognize any events. The only thing I can assume is how I have the layout figured out. Below is the code for the header, along with a visual to go along with it.

**CODE:**

```
private void addHeader()
{
    headPane = new JPanel();
    headPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(headPane, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
    buttonPane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 5, 2));
    buttonPane.setBackground(mouseLineColor);
    headPane.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    Font buttonFont = new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 18);
    minimize.setFocusable(false);
    minimize.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 20));
    minimize.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    minimize.setOpaque(false);
    minimize.setBorder(null);
    minimize.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    minimize.setOpaque(true);
    minimize.setFont(buttonFont);
    minimize.setBackground(buttonColor);

    quit.setFocusable(false);
    quit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 20));
    quit.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    quit.setOpaque(false);
    quit.setBorder(null);
    quit.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    quit.setOpaque(true);
    quit.setFont(buttonFont);
    quit.setBackground(buttonColor);

    back.setFocusable(false);
    back.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 20));
    back.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    back.setOpaque(false);
    back.setBorder(null);
    back.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    back.setOpaque(true);
    back.setFont(buttonFont);
    back.setBackground(buttonColor);

    if(screen != GAME_MENU)
        buttonPane.add(back);
    else
        buttonPane.remove(back);

    buttonPane.add(minimize);
    buttonPane.add(quit);

    headTitle = new JLabel("Bouncy Ball Version " + VERSION);
    headTitle.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 5, 0, 0));
    headTitle.setFont(new Font("", Font.BOLD, 14));
    headTitle.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    headTitle.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    headTitle.setOpaque(true);
    headTitle.setFocusable(false);
    headPane.setFocusable(false);
    buttonPane.setFocusable(false);

    buttonPane.setBackground(Color.RED);

    headPane.add(headTitle);
    headPane.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    headPane.add(buttonPane);

    if(callOnce)
    {
        minimize.addActionListener(this);
        quit.addActionListener(this);
        back.addActionListener(this);

        minimize.addMouseListener(this);
        quit.addMouseListener(this);
        back.addMouseListener(this);

        headPane.addMouseListener(this);
        headPane.addMouseMotionListener(this);

        callOnce = false;
    }

    headPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(headPane.getPreferredSize().width, 24));
    frame.add(headPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
```

**LISTENERS:**

MousePressed:

```
Object source = e.getSource();
if(source == headPane)
{
    mouseX = e.getX();
    mouseY = e.getY();
    movingWindow = true;
}
```

MouseDragged:

```
Object source = e.getSource();
if(source == headPane)
{
    if(movingWindow)
    {
        int x = e.getXOnScreen();
        int y = e.getYOnScreen();
        frame.setLocation(x - mouseX, y - mouseY);
    }
}
```

[image]

I'll also add that when I click on the `headPane`, the `JButton`s will cease to work as well. I don't know why it's doing this, or if the answer is really simple and I'm just being stupid, but nothing I have tried has worked.

I'm fairly new to Java so thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) (rather than just uncompilable code snippets). 2) *".. thanks in advance for any help."* It'd help if you asked a question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no need for the "callOnce" variable. The frame and the components added to the frame should only be created once when the class is created. If you are calling the "addHeader()" method more than once, then I suggest you have a design problem.

Also you should not be adding the ActionListeners to your buttons twice.

> The only problem I'm having is making the window move when you drag this 'custom header'.

Check out [Moving Windows](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) for a general purpose class that allows you to drag any component. Typically you would drag a component within a panel.

However, the class also has a feature that allows you to drag a window on the desktop by dragging a component added to the window.

Comment: That Moving Windows class is very useful, and worked perfectly for what I needed, so thank you very much. I do have a question though about adding the header itself. I do call the "addHeader()" method more than once, primarily because of the back button that I have in place. Whenever you move to a different screen, I have it recall the "addHeader()" method to determine whether or not the back button should be there. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Oh and one more thing that you may or may not be able to answer, is there a way to get the Moving Windows class to work across multiple monitors?

Comment: @Ryan, No need to recreate the entire panel. You could just enable/disable the Back button as required. Or you could make the Back button visible/invisible. I have never played with multiple monitors so I don't know what would be needed to get the ComponentMover to work with multiple monitors.

Comment: I didn't think of toggling the visibility. And as for the multiple monitors, it's not all that big a deal and I'll keep on the lookout for a work-around. Thanks again for all your help.